# Polling interface names via SIOCGIFCONF in Linux

Tags: c, linux, networking

I'm attempting to poll networking device names.  I've pieced this together from various snippets,

1. http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?netdevice+7
2. http://lists.apple.com/archives/Unix-porting/2002/Apr/msg00134.html
3. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1421487

But my output is just gibberish.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <net/route.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <net/if.h>

#define BUFLEN 1024
#define SEQ 9999

int main (int argc, const char* argv[])
{
  // File descriptor for socket
  int socketfd;
  struct ifconf conf;
  struct ifreq req[10];
  struct ifreq *ifr;

  printf("Opening socket...");
  socketfd = socket(AF_ROUTE, SOCK_RAW, 0);
  if (socketfd >= 0) {
    printf(" OK\n");
    conf.ifc_len = sizeof(req);
    conf.ifc_buf = (__caddr_t) req;
    ioctl(socketfd,SIOCGIFCONF,&conf);

    printf("Discovering interfaces...\n");
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<conf.ifc_len/sizeof(req[0]); i++) {
      ifr = &conf.ifc_req[i];
      printf("%d. %s\n", i+1, req[i].ifr_name);
    }
  }
  else {
    printf("Failed!\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Opening socket... OK
Discovering interfaces...
?u???}??Gh???
2. p?9}?
3.
4. v?=?n??u?`?y??]g?<?~?v??
5.
6.
7.
8. ?v?T?
9. ?|?mw??j??v??h??|??v?T00~??v?$?|??|?@
10. T00~??v?$?|??|?@
```

I tried outputting each char of the ifr_name array one-by-one to see if they were null terminated but that didn't change much.  Each iteration of my program outputs something different so this leads me to think I'm referencing something wrong.  Can someone provide me some insight as to what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: You don't check the return value from ioctl().  Likely it's EOPNOTSUPP, that's why the values in the buffer don't make any sense.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Please see http://git.netfilter.org/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=libmnl.git;a=blob;f=examples/rtnl/rtnl-link-dump.c;hb=HEAD on how to get the list of interfaces on Linux. AF_ROUTE is some BSD thing and the use of ioctl is discouraged on Linux for its apparent limitations (such as to convey multiple addresses on a single interface).

Comment: See this is why I never liked people including links in their answer. Unless you know the information on the webpage you are directing readers to go to WON'T never be removed or deleted, then don't include a link in your answer. This user should have just copied that rtnl-link-dump.c code right in his answer.

Comment: tl;dr; link is dead :-(

Comment: Links are fine as long as they are not required reading in order to understand the answer.  Unfortunately, now that it has a dead link, this answer is no good.

Comment: Fixed (for now) link: http://git.netfilter.org/libmnl/tree/examples/rtnl/rtnl-link-dump.c

Answer (score 9):

Here's some code I put together for Mac OS X:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

/* This is defined on Mac OS X */
#ifndef _SIZEOF_ADDR_IFREQ
#define _SIZEOF_ADDR_IFREQ sizeof
#endif

int main (int argc, const char* argv[])
{
  // File descriptor for socket
  int socketfd;
  struct ifconf conf;
  char data[4096];
  struct ifreq *ifr;
  char addrbuf[1024];
  int i;

  printf("Opening socket...");
  socketfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
  if (socketfd >= 0) {
    printf(" OK\n");
    conf.ifc_len = sizeof(data);
    conf.ifc_buf = (caddr_t) data;
    if (ioctl(socketfd,SIOCGIFCONF,&conf) < 0) {
      perror("ioctl");
    }

    printf("Discovering interfaces...\n");
    i = 0;
    ifr = (struct ifreq*)data;
    while ((char*)ifr < data+conf.ifc_len) {
      switch (ifr->ifr_addr.sa_family) {
        case AF_INET:
            ++i;
            printf("%d. %s : %s\n", i, ifr->ifr_name, inet_ntop(ifr->ifr_addr.sa_family, &((struct sockaddr_in*)&ifr->ifr_addr)->sin_addr, addrbuf, sizeof(addrbuf)));
            break;
#if 0
        case AF_INET6:
            ++i;
            printf("%d. %s : %s\n", i, ifr->ifr_name, inet_ntop(ifr->ifr_addr.sa_family, &((struct sockaddr_in6*)&ifr->ifr_addr)->sin6_addr, addrbuf, sizeof(addrbuf)));
            break;
#endif
      }
      ifr = (struct ifreq*)((char*)ifr +_SIZEOF_ADDR_IFREQ(*ifr));
    }
    close(socketfd);
  }
  else {
    printf(" Failed!\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 Nice example, although I'd like to note that your `i` will not represent the actual ifindex of the device, because not all of them will be returned if they are disabled. The buffers are many times bigger than it makes sense for them to be. You have `char addrbuf[1024];` when 17 chars is enough for ipv4 and 40 is enough for ipv6. And `sizeof ifreq` is 40 bytes, which would mean you are allocating space for 102 of those, although this would mean you don't have to check how big buffer you need first. Also you used a while loop when you should use a for loop.

Comment: Also `ifr = (struct ifreq*)((char*)ifr +_SIZEOF_ADDR_IFREQ(*ifr));` can be replaced with `++ifr`

Comment: Hi, on linux, this works if the interface have ip address. for example, if you remove AF_INET6 part, the interfaces with no ipv4 won't show up.

Answer (score 1):

Poll as in you want to be notified if an interface is added or removed?  Or polled as in you just want to find out the interface names once from the system?  If the latter, take a look at [getifaddrs()](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/getifaddrs.3.html).